# Install psycopg2 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to get the python postgres client module installed on Ubuntu 12.04.  The guidance is to do the following:

```
apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

However, `apt` says that the package can't be located.
I'm keen to install this through `apt`.  Is this part of another package that I can install?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 12.04 it appears to work fine for me:

```
jon@minerva:~$ sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
[sudo] password for jon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python-psycopg2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed
  python-psycopg2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 334 not upgraded.
Need to get 153 kB of archives.
```

**What error are you getting exactly?** - double check you've spelt psycopg right - that's quite often a gotcha... and it never hurts to run an `apt-get update` to make sure your repo. is up to date.

Comment: > double check you've spelt psycopg right

Ha! That was my mistake. I was nearly going crazy.

Answer (score 138):

This works for me in Ubuntu 12.04 and 15.10

if pip not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Although the OP wants to use `apt` to install, I still prefer using pip/conda to manage the Python packages.

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu 20.10 x64 and it worked.

Comment: Very helpful...libpq-dev was the catch

Comment: For Python3: sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-flask-migrate -y

Comment: python3-dev is a must for python3

Comment: Never use sudo with pip, I learned it the hard way.

Answer (score 44):

Use

```
sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2
```

for Python3 )

Comment: What about if you want it installed in a Python virtual environment & not system wide?

Comment: This command will install binary package, but in [readme](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) saying that: `The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources`. => So build newest library with `pip` is recommended way

Comment: @AdamParkin apt installs os packages that underly the python package you install in the virtual environment, so there is no way to install an OS level packag to a specific python virtual environment - these are two different levels.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: I get error: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-w6hw2cz7/psycopg2-binary/
`

Answer (score 8):

According to the official documentation https://www.psycopg.org/install/

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 4):

I updated my `requirements.txt` to have
`psycopg2==2.7.4 --no-binary=psycopg2`
So that it build binaries on source

Comment: That is! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should install the library using pip, but this requires multiple system dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python3-dev
```

Then you can run

```
pip install psycopg2
```

---

### Debugging

If you are missing libpq-dev, you will get the error:

> Error: pg_config executable not found.

If you are missing python3-dev, you will get the error:

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm getting: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 10.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 14.4-1.pgdg18.04+1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using pip in case you are using virtualenv:

1. `apt install libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev`
2. `pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
followed by-
pip install psycopg2

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in venv, should be the same without venv:

- Windows:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

- Ubuntu:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

E.g.:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
```

If you don't have enough rights:

```
sudo pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
```