# when installing psycopg2 on ubuntu 14.04 it gives error pycompile not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, package-managers

When I am trying to install **psycopg2** on **Ubuntu 14.04** it through error that:

> Setting up python-psycopg2 (2.4.5-1build5) ...
>   /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-psycopg2.postinst: 6:
>   /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-psycopg2.postinst: pycompile: not found
>   dpkg: error processing package python-psycopg2 (--configure): 
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 127 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached
>   already

This same error occurs for another packages also. Below is the list of packages:

- python-colorama
- python-distlib
- python-egenix-mxtools
- python-egenix-mxdatetime
- python-html5lib
- python-setuptools
- python-pip
- python-psycopg2
- python-sqlite
- python-virtualenv
- python-wheel

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Note:I am not using any virtual environment. Because virtual environment package itself not installing.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583714/install-psycopg2-on-ubuntu) question

Comment: Main error is pycompile not found.and same error comes for above all the packages.I check my python3.5 and it running properly still it gives error pycompile not found