# Cannot install psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am installing psycopg2 on Ubuntu 15.10 for Python 3.5. I had this issue firstly:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9enc9eqe/psycopg2
```

I cured it with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25855548/3014866

I faced new exception:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ne0zd8lq/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-m286d8vp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ne0zd8lq/psycopg2
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Please paste the full trackback.